# Deployed React App Shows a Blank Page and Console Returns Error 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I am a beginner in React JS. I deployed a React app to Github Pages and apparently it was successful, but the site shows only a blank white page. The console says ‘Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()’. I’d appreciate any help with this. I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.
Here is my repo: https://github.com/toyosicodes/memory-game/tree/master/src. The link to the site itself is https://toyosicodes.github.io/memory-game/

I know questions like mine have been asked; I've spent hours poring over them and trying out the recommended solutions, but they haven't worked in my case.

i apologise if this post isn't perfect - it's my first.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to access your website at https://toyosicodes.github.io/memory-game/ and it seems to be loading fine for me, with the default React template. Would you try clearing cache or waiting some time for DNS updates. github.io is a little slow for deployments and takes some time for changes to be visible. I have sometimes waited 30+ minutes for new changes to be visible.

If you like speedy deployments, I would recommend using a service like Vercel or Heroku.

Comment: This literally just happened now. The site is not showing what it should be, but it's no longer blank... I guess that's an improvement? Thanks for your recommendations. I didn't know this about gh pages. I'll try other services.

Comment: @Toyosi what do you think your website should be showing? I looked at your code and seems like it is the create react app template and that's exactly what I see when I open your site.

Comment: @Toyosi, I am facing same issue as blank page, have you got any solution for the same ?